# React (Native) how to make a component reusable when passing different data to iterate and callbacks from parent as well as child to grandchild?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component thats opening and showing a modal that I want to reuse because almost everything I need in multiple places. Whats different is 1. data I am iterating through (property names are different) and 2. the button that triggers the modal has different styling. The problem is also that from the parent components I pass a callback, however, I also need to pass a callback to the part where I iterate/render data another callback coming from child component which is why I cannot just render the data iteration as children prop (thus always passing different data). I tried to implement a renderprop but also failed. I hope I explained not too confusing!! How do I do it?

```
const Parent1 = () => {
    const [reportedLine, setReportedLine] = useState(null);
    const [availableLines, setAvailableLines] = useState([]);
    const [searchResultId, setSearchResultId] = useState('');

    return (
        <AvailableLinesSelector
            data={availableLines}
            disabled={searchResultId}
            onSelect={setReportedLine}
        />
    )
};
```

```
const Parent2 = () => {
    const [line, setLine] = useState(null);
    return (
        <AvailableLinesSelector
            data={otherData}
            disabled={item}
            onSelect={setLine}
        />
    )
};
```

```
const AvailableLinesSelector = ({data, onSelect, disabled}) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    const [selectedLine, setSelectedLine] = useState('Pick the line');//placeholder should also be flexible

    const handleCancel = () => setIsVisible(false);
    const handleSelect = (input) => {
        onSelect(input)
        setSelectedLine(input)
        setIsVisible(false);
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                title={selectedLine}
                //a lot of styling that will be different depending on which parent renders
                disabled={disabled}
                onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}
            />
            <BottomSheet isVisible={isVisible}>
                <View>
                    {data && data.map(line => (
                        <AvailableLine //here the properties as name, _id etc will be different depending on which parent renders this component
                            key={line._id} 
                            line={line.name}
                            onSelect={handleSelect}
                        />
                    ))}
                </View>
                <Button onPress={handleCancel}>Cancel</Button>
            </BottomSheet>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the children and pass additional props like:

```
React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
  if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;

  return React.cloneElement(child, {...child.props, myCallback: callback});
});
```